# Filter children by inner list value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

According to the previous image
Is it possible to get every child of  that matches the value of "11000" in  that is inside the array  ? 
(there might be multiple entries for )

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you start. From `/planes/PaMé7800_..._785/directiones` it is definitely possible. But from `/planes` it is not possible, since you can only query values at a known path under each child.

Essentially your current structure allows you to efficiently find the directiones for each plane, but is does not allow you to efficiently find the planes for a directione. If you want to allow the latter, consider adding an additional data structure for it. For example:

```
directionesStCPToPlanes
  dir11000
    PaMé7800_..._785: true
```

With this additional data structure, you can also look up the inverse relation.

This type of double data storage is quite common and is known as denormalizing the data. For more on this, see:

- [Many-to-many using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416017/many-to-many-using-firebase)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)